Is it possible to pass 2 objects inside an array in Synapse parameter?
I am using a stored procedure in synapse to create a view. This stored procedure written inside a ForEach group and I Need to pass view name and column name dynamically as an Array parameter in ForEach  group.
I tried like this but it is not working.
[{"ViewName":"Table1","ColumnList":"file_name,field2"}]


You can follow below procedure to achieve your requirement:
Create an array pipeline parameter viewPrams with value
[{"ViewName": "view1", "ColumnList": "Id,Name"},{"ViewName": "view2", "ColumnList": "DateOfBirth,Email"} ]
In foreach activity use created parameter as items @pipeline().parameters.viewParams as shown below:

Inside the ForEach activity, add an Execute Stored Procedure activity to call your stored procedure, create parameters as below:

ViewName: @item().ViewName
ColumnList: @item().ColumnList


By following these steps, you should be able to dynamically pass the view name and column list as an array parameter to your ForEach activity in Synapse. And after successful execution of pipeline, you will be able to create views successfully. List the views using below query:
SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA,
       TABLE_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS
ORDER BY TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME;

Output:


I already tried like this but it is not working.

Are you getting any error?

yes. I am getting error like Unable to parse expression 'ViewName'

Check the expression in ViewName parameter, can you provide it?

I am using delta format file as my input. will it work for delta file?
